# refresh sharepoint PAGE using power automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sharepoint-list, power-automate-desktop

I have a sharepoint page with the following web elements-
1.microsoft forms.
2.sharepoint list.

In the same page, towards the left, in the Microsoft forms section , the user answers few questions and submits it.
In the section towards the right, i.e., SharePoint list gets updated with the answers , using POWER Automate.

But the user doesn't know when to refresh this PAGE as the results might still keep populating.

So i am looking for a method where we can refresh the sharepoint page AUTOMATICALLY, once power automate completes the flow

Comment: Not sure if you can refresh the page. It is worth investigating if the trigger contains a referrer url or something similar. I haven't seen that before tbh. That being said, you can definitely sent a notification (email/teams messages/etc.) at the end of the flow to the responder/submitter of the form. This way you can let them know the flow is done and they can refresh.

Comment: Yes but I am trying more of a UI experience to the user by displaying the results with automatic refresh. Thanks :) I will also try script editor and let you know if that worked

Answer (score 0):

I have made a test on my side and couldn't find a way to refresh the sharepoint path within Power Automate. The function to refresh the sharepoint page in not supported in Power Automate currently and you could only refresh the page by manually.
Suggest you do what Expiscornovus said and send a notification to the responder/submitter of the form at the end of the process.
Please refer to: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-an-email-to-responder-when-response-submitted-in-Microsoft/td-p/1485135

Comment: Yes but I am trying more of a UI experience to the user by displaying the results with automatic refresh. Thanks :) I will also try script editor and let you know if that worked